# Finding if a user's ID exists in the database and displaying a button if it doesn't

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a bit of advice on the best way to tackle an if statement.

I have a registration type site, built in Laravel 5.1, and I want new users to fill out a questionnaire.

The way I want to do this is to display a button for them to click on my homepage, however I only want it to be displayed if they haven't filled one out yet.

I've been toying around with how to do this for a while, however I can't find the right solution.

The way I initially did this was retrieve all the results of the table in my routes.php file and passed this in to the view, like so:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $data = Questionnaire::all();
    return View::make('home')->with('data', $data);
});
```

And this returns all the data in the table in an array, that I then tried to loop through these with a foreach, matching the `memberid` field in the array against `Auth::user->id()`. And if no match was found then place the button on the page. However this will always display the button because it always finds a set that don't match, even if it finds a match later on.

At the end of the day, I want to compare the memberid values in my questionnaire table against the id of the member logged in and if they aren't in the questionnaire table then display the button. However, the homepage can be accessed before they're logged in and so simply using a where clause in the route file doesn't always work:

`$data = Questionnaire::where("memberid", "=", Auth::user->id());`

As it will fail if they aren't logged in.

Any solutions on how to solve this?

Comment: So the output must be if the users `Auth::user()->id` of users is equal to the `member_id` in the database? What should i see when i logged in?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a better solution is to pass to the model id member and get the record if it exist, and if it does not, receive null, for example:

```
$member_quest = Questionnaire::where('memberid', $member_id)->first();
```

This solution will tell you whether the record exists or not.

Regarding a button on the home page, you may want to first make sure you are logged into the system, and if so, check the above query to know when questionnaire is filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare only the `member_id` and `Auth::user()->id`. Then try this:

In your controller:

```
  $data = Qustionaire::where('member_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
  return View::make('home',compact('data') );
```

In view:

```
 @if Auth::check() //this code checks if the user is logged in or not
   @if Auth::user->id == $data->id
     //Do something
   @else
     <button>MyButton</button>
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: What happens then if the member isn't logged in yet, wouldnt calling Auth::user fail because it can't find a logged in user?

Comment: You can use the Auth::check(). I will update my answer

Comment: What happens then if someone accesses the page as a guest? Won't the query fail in the controller and throw an error?

Comment: Or would you just use the Auth::check() in the controller as well?

Comment: You may use Route::filter() to compare User to Guest. Here's the link for Route filters http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: Yes, you can also have Auth::check in your controller as well for checking purposes

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to solve this.  Here's what I'd probably do. I would make the questionnaire table a one to one relation to the users table. (see http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

This allows you do do something like:

```
if($user->questionnaire) { .. }
```

That doesnt yet solve the problem of the user not being logged in. You can solve that by passing Auth::user() to the view. For instance like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
  return View::make('home')->with('user', \Auth::user());
});
```

In your view you can now check like this:

```
@if($user and $user->questionnaire === false)
  // show questionnaire button
@endif
```

This assumes you dont want to show the button to people that arent logged in.